# How to select single radio button in ion-radio-group in ionic4

Tags: arrays, ionic4, ion-radio-group

I am building an ionic4 app which uses ion-radio-group to display options from an array. My problem is when I try to select a single radio, all radios are selected. How can I select a single radio?

The code I am using is:

```
                <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="singleanswer">
                  <ion-item *ngFor="let answer of question.answers">
                      <ion-label>{{answer}}</ion-label>
                      <ion-radio value="answer">
                      </ion-radio>
                  </ion-item>
                </ion-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lol! there was a typo in the code.

```
<ion-radio value="answer">
```

was supposed to be

```
<ion-radio value="{{answer}}">
```